# Calabash android, as clicking a ListView?

Tags: android, calabash

I've been looking for the answer on the Internet, but could not find it. help me please.
How to make pressing the list item in Calabash-Android?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Can yo provide more details? What do you have and what do you want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out

Add a definition to ruby step file.

```
Then /^I scroll to cell with "([^\"]*)" label and touch it$/ do |name|
    element="TextView text:'#{name}'"      
    if !element_exists(element)
        wait_poll(:until_exists => "TextView text:'#{name}'", :timeout => WAIT_TIMEOUT) do
            performAction('scroll_down')
        end
        if element_exists(element)
            touch(element)
            sleep(STEP_PAUSE)
        else
            screenshot_and_raise "could not find the cell"
        end
        else
            touch(element)
            sleep(STEP_PAUSE)
        end
end
```

and call it from feature file `Then I scroll to cell with "cellMainLabel" label and touch it`

Answer (score 0):

The answer above looks a bit more fool proof than mine but I have been using the following quite happily:

```
spinner selection  

Then (/^I select spinner by id "(.*?)"$/) do |spinnerid|  
   touch("spinner id:'#{spinnerid}'")  
end

select an item in the damn spinner  

Then (/^I touch "(.*?)"$/) do |text|  
    touch("TextView text:'#{text}'")  
end
```

it's two steps, first part will select the spinner via its id and then the second part selects the item in the spinner via the text you quoted.