# Calabash - Touch the list item of a list view for android

Tags: android, ruby, cucumber, calabash

Can anyone please guide me on how to touch an item of a list view; I had used each_cell method for iOS but the same is not working for android.

It throws me an error - `undefined method`each_cell' for # (NoMethodError)`

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calabash android, as clicking a ListView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22891225/calabash-android-as-clicking-a-listview)

Comment: @Selva, Kindly share few code and screenshot of your list view.

Answer (score 0):

Once i needed to go throw list in a calendar to exact month and i wrote in .rb script to move across until i see element. We open a githut repo but havent commit all .rb codes for calabash-android and probably i won't do it becouse project is in idle state.

```
# All elements are inside table which we use to touch alle list elements
#  |  x1  |
#  |  x2  |
#  |  x3  |
#  |  x4  |
# screen shoots go to external folders to make it more clear when you want to see what happend during test

def moveThroughtList(table)
    begin
        # Create Assoc array
        data = table.raw
        # Go throw all table elements
        data.each do |identifiers|
            identifiers.each do |identifier|
                #go inside category
                tap_when_element_exists("* {text CONTAINS[c] '#{identifier}'}")
                sleep(1)
                screenshot(options = {:prefix => 'screenshots/', :name => 'category_inside'})
                press_back_button
            end
        end
        #It catch all errors and prevent test to stop
    rescue Calabash::Android::WaitHelpers::WaitError => e
        puts "Error someting went wrong continue test"
        #In case of fail do this
    else
        screenshot(options = {:prefix => 'screenshots/errors/', :name => 'errors'})
        press_back_button
    end
end
```